# How to write a procedure?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, procedural-programming

**Hello!** Help me please to make **a procedure from my program code**.
I've got code, which includs 2 parts (they're Graphics[...]), it plots functions with rectengles.
But it seems to be too much code, so I have to write a procedure with an argument of a function and then when I call it, this procedure would do the same (plots functions with rectengles). (can somehows to use spx1,spx2.)

This is whole code:

```
        (*Sin[x]*)
data1 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 6, 0.1}];
    data11 = data1[[;; , 2]];(*отримуємо набір ординат*)localmins1 = 
     Pick[data1, MinDetect[data11, 10^-6], 1];
    localmaxs1 = Pick[data1, MaxDetect[data11, 10^-6], 1];
    Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[data1], Red, PointSize[0.01], 
       Point[localmins1], Point[localmaxs1]}, Axes -> True];       

spx1 = {-1, -0.35, 0.3, 0.95, 1.6, 2.375, 3.15, 3.925, 4.7, 6};
    Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[data1], Red, PointSize[0.01], 
      Point[localmins1], Point[localmaxs1], 
      Point[{{-1, 0}, {1.6, 0}, {-0.35, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.95, 0}}], Green, 
      Point[{{-0.35, -0.1342898}, {0.3, 0.29552}, {0.95, 0.813416}}], Red,
       Point[{{2.375, 0}, {3.15, 0}, {3.925, 0}, {4.7, 0}}], Green, 
      Point[{{2.375, 0.693685}, {3.15, -0.0084}, {3.925, -0.70569766}}], 
      Pink, Opacity[.7], EdgeForm[Directive[Dashed, Pink]], 
      Rectangle[{-1, -0.84147}, {-0.35, -0.342898}], 
      Rectangle[{-0.35, -0.342898}, {0.3, 0.29552}], 
      Rectangle[{0.3, 0.29552}, {0.95, 0.813416}], 
      Rectangle[{0.95, 0.813416}, {1.6`, 0.9995736030415051`}], 
      Rectangle[{1.6, 0.99957}, {2.375, 0.693685}], 
      Rectangle[{2.375, 0.693685}, {3.15, -0.0084}], 
      Rectangle[{3.15, -0.0084}, {3.925, -0.70569766}], 
      Rectangle[{3.925, -0.70569766}, {4.7, -0.9999}],}, Axes -> True]

    (*Cos[x]*)
    data2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, -3, 4, 0.1}]; data22 = 
     data2[[;; , 2]];(*отримуємо набір ординат*)localmins2 = 
     Pick[data2, MinDetect[data22, 10^-6], 1];
    localmaxs2 = Pick[data2, MaxDetect[data22, 10^-6], 1];
    Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[data2], Red, PointSize[0.01], 
       Point[localmins2], Point[localmaxs2]}, Axes -> True];

    spx2 = {-3,-2.25, -1.5, -0.75,0, 0.75, 1.5, 2.25, 3};
    spxrozb11 = {-3, -2.25, -1.5, -0.75, 0};
    spxrozb22 = {0, 0.75, 1.5, 2.25, 3};
    Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[data2], Red, PointSize[0.01], 
      Point[localmins2], Point[localmaxs2], 
      Point[{{-2.25, 0}, {-1.5, 0}, {-0.75, 0}, {0, 0}}], Green, 
      Point[{{-2.25, -0.628}, {-1.5, 0.07}, {-0.75, 0.73}}], Red, 
      Point[{{0.75, 0}, {1.5, 0}, {2.25, 0}, {3, 0}}], Green, 
      Point[{{0.75, 0.7316}, {1.5, 0.07}, {2.25, -0.628}}], Pink, 
      Opacity[.7], EdgeForm[Directive[Dashed, Pink]], 
      Rectangle[{-3, -0.989992}, {-2.25, -0.628}], 
      Rectangle[{-2.25, -0.628}, {-1.5, 0.07}], 
      Rectangle[{-1.5, 0.07}, {-0.75, 0.7316}], 
      Rectangle[{-0.75, 0.7316}, {1.6653345369377348`*^-16, 1.`}], 
      Rectangle[{1.6653345369377348`*^-16, 1.`}, {0.75, 0.7316}], 
      Rectangle[{0.75, 0.7316}, {1.5, 0.07}], 
      Rectangle[{1.5, 0.07}, {2.25, -0.628}], 
      Rectangle[{2.25, -0.628}, {3.1000000000000005`, \
    -0.9991351502732795`}]}, Axes -> True]
```

I tried to write the first step in procedure, and even it doesn't work;(

```
f1 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 6, 0.1}];
f2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, -3, 4, 0.1}];
data = {f1, f2};
spx1 = {-1, -0.35, 0.3, 0.95, 1.6, 2.375, 3.15, 3.925, 4.7, 6};
graph[i_] := 
 Graphics[For[i = 0, i < 3, 
   i++, {Thick, Blue, Line[data[[i]]], Red, Point[{spx1[[i]], 0}]}]]
graph[1]
```

******How to write `For` in procedure correctly?******

Comment: In your code above can you rewrite all your Point and Rectangle in both your Sin and Cos sections just in terms of your data1 and data 2? Or are all those Point and Rectangle numbers going to have to be manually entered for each section? Also, Graphics[...]; displays nothing, because of that semicolon at the end of the line. Is that an error or because you drastically simplified this from what your real problem and question is?

Comment: For the last part, you are trying to use the  function argument `i` as a loop iterator. `i` is given a fixed value ( `1` in the example ) and so can not be changed inside the loop.  ( I cant even figure what your intent is to tell you how to fix that )